# HTML doc not reading CSS file?

Tags: html, css

My question is so simple that I don't know where to begin in problem solving it.

I am working through some HTML tutorials and I have the following files in the same directory:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ntf-8"/>
        <title> Tutorial 24 - pseudo classes</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> You </p>
        <p> Only </p>
        <p> Live </p>
        <p> Once </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and CSS:

```
p:first-letter( 
    color:blue; 
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
)
```

But when I open my HTML file in Chrome it doesn't take my styling...

Comment: Try running your CSS through a linter.

Answer (score 1):

Your css should be using curly braces not parentheses

Answer (score 0):

Invalid Syntax change from this

```
p:first-letter( 
    color:blue; 
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
)
```

To this

```
p:first-letter{
    color:blue; 
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

`()` -> `{}`